# Android Cover Flow with image shadow effect

Tags: android, image, effects, shadow, coverflow

I want to implement cover flow as below

[image: Android Coverflow with image shadow]

I have tried Carousel, but its not the same thing. Did some google search was not able to find something even near to the cover flow implemented in given example.

Comment: can any tell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979903/how-to-reduce-reflection-gap-in-fancycover-flow

Answer (score 2):

Definitely have a look at this, [FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow).

There is a demo app for it in the Play store as well that shows the reflection requirement you'd like.

Comment: not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979903/how-to-reduce-reflection-gap-in-fancycover-flow

Comment: Your page link appears to be broken, however, since it's over a year since I recommended that, and it's no longer maintained, and there's a ton of changes from Lollipop that will likely warrant it unusable or less favorable to newer github goodness, I'd probably consider hunting for something else. Unfortunately I do not know of any alternatives at the moment that have reflection.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

[blog post](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.ro/2013/06/image-with-reflection-in-image-view.html)

```
public Bitmap getRefelection(Bitmap image) {
  // The gap we want between the reflection and the original image
  final int reflectionGap = 0;

  // Get you bit map from drawable folder
  Bitmap originalImage = image;

  int width = originalImage.getWidth();
  int height = originalImage.getHeight();

  // This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
  matrix.preScale(1, -1);

  // Create a Bitmap with the flip matix applied to it.
  // We only want the bottom half of the image
  /*if(bitmapWithReflection!=null && !bitmapWithReflection.isRecycled()){
   bitmapWithReflection.recycle();
   bitmapWithReflection=null;
  }*/
  Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0,
    height / 2, width, height / 2, matrix, false);

  // Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit reflection
  Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,(height + height / 2), Config.ARGB_8888);
  // Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
  // the image plus gap plus reflection
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
  // Draw in the original image
  canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
  //Draw the reflection Image
  canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage, 0, height + reflectionGap, null);

  // Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the reflection
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0,
    originalImage.getHeight(), 0, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight()
      + reflectionGap, 0x40ffffff, 0x00ffffff, TileMode.CLAMP);
  // Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
  paint.setShader(shader);
  // Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
  paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
  // Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
  canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight()
    + reflectionGap, paint);
  if(originalImage!=null && originalImage.isRecycled()){
   originalImage.recycle();
   originalImage=null;
  }
  if(reflectionImage!=null && reflectionImage.isRecycled()){
   reflectionImage.recycle();
   reflectionImage=null;
  }
  return bitmapWithReflection;
 }
```

Comment: thanks @hamad, do you have example of cover flow which implements the reflection, as its half solution to my question :)

Comment: yes but first upvote my answer and mark this as answers for others help and visit this for coverflow source https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/source/browse/

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the [Android Coverflow](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/10/android-coverflow/) which is bit different form the Carousel which you want.

Comment: @GrlsHu, it uses gallery view which is depreciated in API level 16 :(, also reviews on it shows it has many errors.

Comment: I know the galleryview is deprecated its not like that it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I made cover flow widget which is not dependent on gallery.
You can find it here. I will add some samples later.

http://applm.github.io/ma-components/